# Some questions about AMCL

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on amcl recently, I have some questions about it. The tf tree is like the picture below.

[image description http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/13893591131665467.png](http://answers.ros.org/upfiles/13893591131665467.png)

1. I found in other questions that amcl receives information from **tf between odom and base_link** frames, then broadcast **tf between map and odom** frames after correcting to implement localization. I am not sure if I understand correctly.
2. Suppose the coordinate of **odom** under **map** frame is (x1, y1), **base_link** under **odom** is (x2, y2). So if I understand correctly, the coordinate of **base_link** under **map** frame is (x, y), i.e. **x=x1+x2, y=y1+y2**. Is it right?
3. What role does **base_footprint** frame play?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248716/some-questions-about-amcl/) by [MINGLIBRIAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/28378/minglibrian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, it seems your picture about tf tree doesnt have amcl, so I'm not sure if the picture is related to the questions.

Next, following are my thoughts about your questions:

1. You are right. AMCL keeps transform between map and odom. Some node will keep transform between odom and base_link. This node could use difference ways to calculate the transform: motor encoder, laser odometry, imu, fusion of different sensors, etc.
2. Not always true. The reason is it depends on the rotational transform between odom and map. In your example, there is no information about the rotation, so we cant conclude easily. If the odom and map frame have same orientation (meaning no rotational transform between them), then you can conclude `x=x1+x2, y=y1+y2`.
3. `base_link` frame represents the robot body. It varies from different type of robots.

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2016-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1